# How can i use durandal mvc controller in viewpath?

Tags: breeze, durandal

I got

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Roles = AccountRepository.GetRoles();
            return PartialView();
        }
```

So how can i use with CreateUserViewModel with viewPath is Account/CreateUser

I am new at durandal. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Durandal, I'm guessing your trying out a spa (as am I). If so, you really shouldn't need to use the controllers to do this. Rather, on page start up, wrap up the main body of your code with your main js files in a

```
@model MvcApplication7.Models.LoginModel

<div id="main-content">
@if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ///main app here
}
else
{
    ///authorize/sign up here
}
</div>

@if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/duranal")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/etc...")
}
}
```

This is basically the model that the guys at breeze use in their breeze spa sample project which you can find here http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template

good luck!

ps. word on the street is that john papa will have a course coming up on pluralsight soon that I bet will include durandal stuff

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. What i mean is, if you have a module to manage user. And i want use with controller to bind model data to views to load. How can I do it thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert, but I'd say that all the user management should be done on the client. On the start of the application, pass validate the user, and assign them some securitytoken. Your client side js would manage your user based on what roles, actions, etc (maybe this information could be managed in a shell view model which is in the Hot Towel template). Then, when the user attempts to post, put, delete. You verify who they are using that security token that you assigned to that user on the start of the application.

Comment: I may be beating a dead horse though. What are you trying to manage/accomplish? Security, activity, roles?